# How to detect null values when delimiter is unknown?

Tags: python

I am currently working on the automation task of parsing Linux based outputs. We are currently not sure which field values will become null and when.

***Goal: To get all the fields everytime no matter whichever field becomes null in my linux output. If any field is `null` then treat it as a blank field***

Python code that I am using to split the fields: As there are no null fields in the `output` so the following code works as expected

```
fields = "Index    Id        Type              Ip      Flags AhmSt       CLT  AhmDB Nodename"
fields = fields.split()
output = "6215  5097     GOLD1      10.123.43.2        n/a [1,0,0,en]  dflt   u     testing-fake-sme-6-50.gold.isold.com"
values = output.split(' ')
values = [value for value in values if value]

values:
['6215', '5097', 'GOLD1', '10.123.43.2', 'n/a', '[1,0,0,en]', 'dflt', 'u', 'testing-fake-sme-6-50.gold.isold.com']

required_output = dict(zip(fields,values))
required_output:
{'Index': '6215', 'Nodename': 'testing-fake-sme-6-50.gold.isold.com', 'AhmDB': 'u', 'Ip': '10.123.43.2', 'Flags': 'n/a', 'CLT': 'dflt', 'AhmSt': '[1,0,0,en]', 'Type': 'GOLD1', 'Id': '5097'}
```

Now, for the following `output` my `AhmSt` field becomes `null` and the above code doesn't work.

```
output = "270  4142        HOLD     10.123.12.32 0x00000001                    h  hello-ca-4142-20.gold.isold.com
```

***How can I detect in the second output that my `AhmSt` field is null and I have  to update that with `blank` or `None` values?***

Comment: All I see is that `output` is a string. How is represented a null value inside the string?

Comment: Which command are you parsing the output of? Perhaps there might be a better way like patching said command to output in a better format.

Comment: Let's say you've got fields `"Name Age Id", and one of the rows is "Alice 23". Clearly one of the fields in that row is null, but which one is it? Is 23 Alice's age or ID? There's no way to tell. If the file has no delimiter and null values are represented by an empty string, then it's hopelessly ambiguous.

Comment: As @Kevin said, a general solution is impossible. If some of the fields have specific formats, you may be able to solve it with a regular expression. E.g. if `AhmSt` has to be surrounded by `[]`, you can use `(\[[^]]+\])?` to make this field optional. Without knowing all the details of your data format, we can't answer this.

Comment: You're creating yourself a complicated problem. Can't you let the original program output a placeholder like `-` instead of null?